# C++ casting a std::vector<Derived>* to std::vector<Base> ...?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, casting, stl

I'm making a vector of pointers to vectors:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<Base>*> all; // vector keeping pointers to vectors
```

and the problem is I have several vectors of derived classes:

```
    std::vector<Derived1> derived1; // vector of derived class
    std::vector<Derived2> derived2; // vector of derived class
    std::vector<Derived3> derived2; // vector of derived class
```

Is there any safe way to change the type of a pointer from `vector<DerivedX>` to `vector<Base>`?

Every derived class shares certain behavior and they will be alive for most of the program's life.

I'm still not good at explaining my programming problems, should any questions concerning details arise - please ask in comments.

Comment: If it was `std::vector<std::vector<Base*>>` and `std::vector<std::vector<Derived*>>`, you could maybe do something with `std::copy`. However, it's impossible to store an instance of `Derived` in `std::vector<Base>`. If you try, the `Derived` will be "clipped", losing everything that makes it a `Derived` and retaining only that which makes it `Base`. (There's a term for this, but it escapes me at the moment.)

Comment: @celticminstrel the term is *sliced*

Comment: ...which also has another totally unrelated meaning (in `std::valarray` or other languages like Python).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that is not possible. There is no relationship between `std::vector<Base>` and `std::vector<Derived>`.

In other words: `std::vector<Derived>` is NOT derived from `std::vector<Base>`.

Comment: Is there at least ANY way to do it? Isn't vector of pointers in theory able to store any pointer? I just wanted to use the same function on every vector of derived (it only iterates the elements and deletes unneeded ones) and without this kind of conversion I will have to manually add every derived vector to the function instead of running it for size.() or for iterator begin() end ()

Comment: There is no relationship between `std::vector<Derived>` and `std::vector<Base>`. Furthermore, if you tried to force a cast somehow, then you would run into the problem that the memory layout of the contained array of objects is different when sizeof(Derived) is different than sizeof(Base), which is probably going to be the case most of the time.

Comment: Pointer to std::vector<Base> has different memory layout than pointer to std::vector<Derived>?

Comment: @Usomochi Derived likely has different size and very likely different positioning in memory of it's member variables than Base, so the vector's internal array will be a different size and probably be expecting to find the member variables in different places.

Comment: Oh well... I guess I will either play with templates to get similar effect or copy paste the code few times... I kinda forgot about vectors second argument, std::allocator<base> ;)

Comment: It's not so much about allocators, but rather the same fundamental reason that `Derived array[10];` is different than `Base array[10];`

Comment: @Usomochi one possible solution is to use `vector<shared_ptr<Base>>` for all of your vectors (this has pros and cons, which you will discover if you try it)